# Performance of MATLABS memmapfile

Tags: matlab, bigdata, memory-mapping

As we all know memory mapping can be an elegant way to access an extremely large mount of data on disk. 
However, I would like to know whether in MATLAB this advantage is really available or if there are caveats with MATLAB.

A specific question is what the difference between accessing data indirectly with

```
m = memmapfile( ... )           % m is a memmapfile object
z = m.Data.X;
```

or

```
m = memmapfile( ... )           % m is a memmapfile object  
d = m.Data;                     % d is a standard matlab struct
z = d.X;
```

are. I found that the latter is almost twice as fast (see below). Do I still get memory mapping when I assign m.Data to a local variable? It is a standard matlab structure.

Also why does the time for the access to m.Data and the call to memmapfile strongly increase when run several times?

The ouptut of my timing script:

```
memmapfile: 
    open  143.2ms,
    access 125MS Data, downsampled by 4:  454.0ms (561.4297      429.2862      427.1376      424.5907      427.3223)ms, std 60.1ms)
memmapfile: 
    open  99.9ms,
    access 125MS Data: 1609.9ms (1640.7666      1753.8268      1536.2547      1566.3313      1552.0821)ms, std 89.9ms)
memmapfile: 
    open  93.4ms,
    access random Data: 4394.5ms (4847.7417      4510.8818      4238.5909      4200.2644      4174.8181)ms, std 286.9ms)

memmapfile indirect: 
    open  83.9ms,
    access m.Data  2.9ms,
    access 125MS Data, downsampled by 4:  315.0ms (428.3787      445.2119      231.8119      235.2545        234.42)ms, std 111.3ms)
memmapfile indirect: 
    open  878.2ms,
    access m.Data  128.9ms,
    access 125MS Data: 817.3ms (862.5803      945.8177      750.9163      782.6967      744.5202)ms, std 85.8ms)
memmapfile: 
    open  925.5ms,
    access m.Data  134.3ms,
    access random Data: 4252.1ms (4326.7768      4238.1152      4228.8702      4258.6776      4208.0705)ms, std 45.5ms)

load: 
    open  1713.3ms,
    access 125MS Data, downsampled by 4:  252.6ms (269.144      242.3532      233.9538      247.1834      270.6117)ms, std 16.4ms)
load: 
    open  993.7ms,
    access 125MS Data: 776.0ms (737.53      810.9646      769.6092      792.9491      768.7254)ms, std 27.8ms)
load: 
    open  1029.1ms,
    access random Data: 4302.4ms (4320.5536      4314.7477      4320.0803      4287.7655      4268.7568)ms, std 23.1ms)

matfile: 
    open  253.8ms,
    access 125MS Data, downsampled by 4:  879.7ms (948.7214        867.83      861.8788      866.6201      853.6823)ms, std 39.0ms)
matfile: 
    open  7.5ms,
    access 125MS Data: 1431.3ms (1379.7382      1478.5318      1420.7367      1442.8253      1434.4649)ms, std 35.9ms)
matfile: access random Data
    UNSUPPORTED
```

My timing code

```
SIZE = 250e6;
if 0
    X = randn(SIZE,1);
    savefast( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'X' );
    X = [];
end

N = SIZE/2;

I = round( rand(N,1) * N )+1;



%
% memmapfile
%
t = tic;
m = memmapfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Format', {'double', [SIZE, 1], 'X' }, 'Offset', 0, 'Writable', false ); % use dumy data file
fprintf( 'memmapfile: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data, downsampled by 4: ', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.Data.X(1:4:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


t = tic;
m = memmapfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Format', { 'double', [SIZE, 1], 'X' }, 'Offset', 0, 'Writable', false ); % use dumy data file
fprintf( 'memmapfile: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data:', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.Data.X(1:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


t = tic;
m = memmapfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Format', {'double', [SIZE, 1], 'X' }, 'Offset', 0, 'Writable', false ); % use dumy data file
fprintf( 'memmapfile: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess random Data:');
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.Data.X(I);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


%
% memmapfile indirect
%
fprintf('\n');
t = tic;
m = memmapfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Format', {'double', [SIZE, 1], 'X' }, 'Offset', 0, 'Writable', false ); % use dumy data file
fprintf( 'memmapfile indirect: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
t = tic;
d = m.Data;
fprintf( '\taccess m.Data % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data, downsampled by 4: ', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = d.X(1:4:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


t = tic;
m = memmapfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Format', {'double', [SIZE, 1], 'X' }, 'Offset', 0, 'Writable', false ); % use dumy data file
fprintf( 'memmapfile indirect: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
t = tic;
d = m.Data;
fprintf( '\taccess m.Data % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data:', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = d.X(1:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


t = tic;
m = memmapfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Format', {'double', [SIZE, 1], 'X' }, 'Offset', 0, 'Writable', false ); % use dumy data file
fprintf( 'memmapfile: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
t = tic;
d = m.Data;
fprintf( '\taccess m.Data % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess random Data:');
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = d.X(I);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


%
% load
%
fprintf('\n');
t = tic;
m = load( 'test_memmapfile.mat' );
fprintf( 'load: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data, downsampled by 4: ', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.X(1:4:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


t = tic;
m = load( 'test_memmapfile.mat' );
fprintf( 'load: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data:', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.X(1:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


t = tic;
m = load( 'test_memmapfile.mat' );
fprintf( 'load: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess random Data:');
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.X(I);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


%
% matfile
%
fprintf('\n');
t = tic;
m = matfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Writable', false );
fprintf( 'matfile: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data, downsampled by 4: ', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.X(1:4:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


t = tic;
m = matfile( 'test_memmapfile.mat', 'Writable', false );
fprintf( 'matfile: \n\topen % 3.1fms,\n', toc(t)*1e3 );
fprintf('\taccess %dMS Data:', N/1e6);
tt = [];
for ii=1:5
    t = tic;
    z = m.X(1:N,:);
    tt(end+1) = toc(t);
end
fprintf( '% 3.1fms (%s)ms, std %0.1fms)\n', mean(tt)*1e3, num2str(tt*1e3), std(tt)*1e3 );


fprintf('matfile: access random Data\n');
fprintf('\tUNSUPPORTED\n');
```